# i am having issues with react-native ios build - Expected a type error in one of Library

Tags: ios, react-native, jwplayer

Error in react-native-jw-media-player
and was working fine on my previous m1 mac mini

[image: Image screen shot]

environment:

Macbook M1 Pro
XCODE 13.4.1

Comment: Check if JWPlayerKit is properly installed in node modules. Because iOS is unable to find that module definition it's giving the error.

Comment: @msusare Yes, I checked properly. Also, it is taking to the definition of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way to resolve this issue

Go to `Finder` -> `Applications`

Right click on `Xcode` app and click on `Get Info`

You'll see this window

[image]

Make sure `Open using Rosetta` is checked. If now mark it checked and close.

Restart your Xcode, clean build folder and build again.

Hope it resolves the issue!